# calling DLL method from WinDev

Tags: c#, c++, dll, import, windev

I want use a DLL (developed in C++) in WinDev application , my DLL works fine with C# code and i can call any method in there , however with Windev i can successfuly load the DLL using :

`hInst = LoadDLL("MyDLL.DLL")`

but when i want invoke a method this way :

```
CallDLL32("MyDLL", "GetCode", data, res1, res2)
```

i got an error **"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."**

the method signature that i want call is like this way :

```
string GetCode([IN] byte[] Data, [OUT] string res1, [OUT] string res2)
```

Comment: Problem solved : i used an assembler .net from windev and needs to convert string array to byte array 

`sMyString is string = "votre chaine de caractère"
nDimension is int = Length(sMyString)
tabByteArray is array of nDimension 1-byte int

K is int
FOR K = 1 TO nDimension
tabArray[K] = ASC(Middle(sMyString, K, 1))
END`

Answer (score 0):

This [post](http://forum.pcsoft.fr/fr-FR/pcsoft.fr.windev.old/16072-wd14-appel-dll/read.awp) in french  suggest that you prefix the strings with & because it need to be pass by reference, it should probably looks like :

```
CallDLL32("MyDLL", "GetCode", &data, &res1, &res2)
```

Though I don't know how it works with an array of bytes.

Answer (score -1):

You can call Directely: API function

```
API("USER32", "SendMessageA", hWnd, wMsg, lParam1, lParam2)
```

documentation: https://doc.windev.com/en-US/?3014005

Comment: I dont know who gave me -1 and why? If my solution is wrong...he can tell me the mistake. This is a tested solution with documentation link